# How can I change a translation for a string in a plugin?

Tags: plugins, translation

I'm only starting with WordPress development so please be gentle :)

I'm using the Amelia Booking plugin and am trying to change the string `"On-site (Bank Transfers Only)"` which is defined in the `getCommonStrings()` function in the plugin's `translations.php` file as follows:

```php
'on_site' => __('On-site (Bank Transfers Only)', 'wpamelia')
```

This is not a problem at all to change it right there but I will lose my changes after every plugin update I guess.

So, I was thinking to add those changes to the child theme somehow, but I have no idea how to proceed. Can you please point me out the correct way of doing this?
Thanks so much.
Kind Regards

Comment: "translations.php file in the plugin folder" - that's not the normal way to do translations. You can hook into the normal way (although that always seemed a nasty hack to me) but I've no idea if there's a nicer way to fix this. Which plugin? Is the translations.php available somewhere for us to look at?

Comment: If there's no way to hook in then you can fork the plugin: give it a different name so it doesn't get overwritten by automatic updates, or filter the automatic updates so that it doesn't get updated. But then you'll need to update it manually. You could set up your own automatic-update-with-patches process but there's nothing built into WordPress that would do that.

Comment: Yes of course here is a FrontendStrings.php file available: 
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvpKKF-U2QNjjstW38BUZAmmn6o5Hw
I just need to change a few strings that's it but of course would be nice to not have this overwritten in the future. I'm doing manual updates for this plugin anyway, so I can always upload the old file after the update but this is not what I'm looking for ofcourse. 

The plugin is called Amelia Booking by TMS

Comment: I would like to change exactly this string (Line 158)*****
'on_site'                      => __('On-site (Bank Transfers Only)', 'wpamelia'),*****  which belongs directly to function called "public static function getCommonStrings()" (Line 65)

Comment: What is the plugin you're trying to modified called? I think you've fallen into the X Y problem trap, where you want to replace a translation string in a plugin, but rather than asking how to do that, you've devised a solution then ran into a problem, and asked how to fix your solution instead of how to solve your problem.

Comment: I'd look for the function that calls getAllStrings and see if there's a filter there that you can hook into and change it. But `__('On-site (Bank Transfers Only)', 'wpamelia'),` is using WordPress's built-in translation mechanism after all, so you can use the hack method, a [gettext filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/gettext/).

Comment: @Tom J Nowell; I guess you're right, I was trying to find the way but because I'm a complete beginner yes I would like to ask you guys how to do it :) @Rup; can you help me understand how can I use that get_text filter and where should I use it? In the functions.php file in the Child Theme folder?

Comment: Ok, I will do it probably by always updating this file after plugin manual update, hassle free and right for my knowledge level at this time. Thanks guys anyway